# I just upgraded to 17.10 from 17.04: library not found for gedit

Tags: 17.10, gedit

After upgrading to 17.10 from 17.04 a couple of hours ago, I cannot use gedit, apparently because a library could not be found:

```
tscale@tscale-mbp-ubuntu:~$ gedit
gedit: /snap/meshlab-mardy/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)
```

I don't know why `snap/meshlab-mardy/` directory is shown, but perhaps it is the last `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` searched?

I tried using

```
apt-get install libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11'
```

to no avail.

How do I get back to using gedit?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the`meshlab-mardy` snap has a version of `libstdc++` in it, which is incompatible with the version in 17.10 which the system `libmirclient` is linked to, and is being used for some reason. This should be reported to the owner of the snap as a bug.

If you remove the `meshlab-mardy` then gedit should work again.

Comment: Dobey: Thank you. Update: The response to 'sudo snap list' did not include gedit; perhaps because it was already installed in all of the prior ubuntu versions I have used on this computer. So, I purged using apt-get (sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gedit'), then installed using 'snap install gedit'. I was informed I also needed to install 'gnome-3-26-1604; so I did. And I 'connected' gedit to gnome. Gedit ran, but I could not save modified files. Very frustrating. Tim

Comment: Oh. What is `meshlab-mardy` exactly? Do you use it? Perhaps you should remove it, though I don't know why a .deb package would be loading a library from it.

Comment: I just removed meshlab-mardy (meshlab is a very useful meshing program - for finite element analyses), after reinstalling gedit using apt-get. Gedit now works. So - all is good, for now. I will have to install meshlab again, when needed . . .  we will see. Thanks! Tim